# Scroll to bottom of listbox wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox with more than 20 items. How I can scroll to bottom of it?
I tried the `ScrollIntoView` method, but no success:

```
listmy.SelectedIndex = listmy.Items.Count;// listmy.Items.Count - 1;
            listmy.ScrollIntoView(listmy.SelectedIndex);
            listmy.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx) method expects an object (the item to scroll to), but you are passing in the numeric index of the selected item.  This will work:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listmy.SelectedIndex = listmy.Items.Count - 1;
    listmy.ScrollIntoView(listmy.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: (As suggested by Ernest)Also had to call listmy.UpdateLayout();

Answer (score 3):

Call UpdateLayout before ScrollIntoView

```
var item = listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 1];
listmy.UpdateLayout();
listmy.ScrollIntoView(item);
listmy.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: This method is not working properly. Imagein you use ObservableCollectioin<string> as an Item Source. It works fine until you enter the same string as previous. In this case you will be positioned on your first value of string...