# ListBox.SelectedItem working but doesn't scroll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, listbox

I am using below code to bind my listBox SelectedItem using MVVM. However the item is selected but it doesn't scroll to the selected item.

```
public int CollectedItem
        {
            get { return _collectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _collectedItem)
                    return;

                _collectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CollectedItem");
                SelectedItem = ChapterContent.Find(x => x.ArabicText.AyaID == _collectedItem);
            }
        }
        public ArabicTextWithTranslation SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedItem)
                    _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }

        }
```

XAML Page

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbReadingChapter" ItemsSource="{Binding ChapterContent}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

Code behind in Page Load

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (DataContext as MainChapaterViewModel).CollectedItem = 10;
            this.lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = lsbReadingChapter.Items.Count - 1;
            this.lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
            this.lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);

            this.lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = 10;
            this.lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
            this.lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(10);

            //scrollIntoSelectedItem(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);
        }
```

It's very annoying, The item is selected as the event occurs when I debug the code, but it doesn't scroll to the selected index or item.

Thanks!

Comment: Read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827489/scroll-wpf-listbox-to-the-selecteditem-set-in-code-in-a-view-model

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're going wrong with the `ScrollIntoView`:

[How to Scroll into selected item in listbox in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101249/)

Reference: [Scroll to bottom of listbox wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657923/)